# To avoid cyclic refernce in Recursive CTE with 2 tables for Oracle / SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

There are 2 tables Department and subdepartment which have id in common. I am trying to recursively fetch all the ids reporting to AB directly and indirectly. BC is reporting to AB, hence 4,5,6 are indirectly reporting to AB, likewise fetching till the last id.

There exists a cyclic reference for Id 9 to BC. I want to avoid the cyclic reference.
I am trying in Oracle 11g and SQL server 2012
Department

```
Name     id
AB          1
AB          2
AB          3
BC          4
BC          5
BC          6
CD          7
CD          8
EF          9
EF         10
EF         11
```

Subdepartment

```
ID      Reporting
1
2
3         BC
4
5         CD
6
7
8         EF
9         BC
10
11
```

Query:

```
With reportinghierarchy (Name, Id, Reporting, lvl) As
    (   
    --Anchor
    Select A.name,
           A.id,
           reporting,
           0 
    from department A, 
         subdepartment B
    where A.id=B.id 
    and A.name='AB'        
    Union All        
    --Recursive member
    Select C.name,
           C.id,
           D.reporting, 
           lvl+1 
    from department C, 
         subdepartment D, 
         reportinghierarchy R
    Where C.name != 'AB' 
    and C.Id =D.id 
    and C.Name = R.reporting
    And R.Reporting is not null
    )
Select * from reportinghierarchy;
```

Getting error as 'ORA-32044:cycle detected while executing recursive WITH'

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just looking for the `cycle` clause:

```
with reportinghierarchy (name, id, reporting, lvl) as
(
  select a.name, a.id, reporting, 0
  from department a
  join subdepartment b
  on b.id = a.id
  where a.name='AB'
  union all
  select c.name, c.id, d.reporting, lvl+1
  from reportinghierarchy r
  join department c
  on c.name = r.reporting
  join subdepartment d
  on d.id = c.id
  where c.name != 'AB'
  and r.reporting is not null
)
cycle reporting set is_cycle to 1 default 0
select *
from reportinghierarchy;
```

which with your sample date gives:

```
NAME         ID REPORTING        LVL I
---- ---------- --------- ---------- -
AB            1                    0 0
AB            2                    0 0
AB            3 BC                 0 0
BC            6                    1 0
BC            5 CD                 1 0
BC            4                    1 0
CD            8 EF                 2 0
CD            7                    2 0
EF           11                    3 0
EF           10                    3 0
EF            9 BC                 3 1

11 rows selected.
```

You can filter on the `is_cycle` pseudocolumn, and/or exclude it from the result set by listing the columns you *do* want to see instead of using `*`.

Read more about how recursive subquery factoring works [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6).

Comment: Thx got it working for oracle. What is equivalent for cycle is SQL

Comment: @EmilJoshva - this is SQL...? Oh, you mean SQL Server? No idea I'm afraid.